# Should a tag be it's own resource or a nested property?

Tags: rest, tags, api-design

I am at a crossroads deciding whether tags should be their own resource or a nested property of a note. This question touches a bit on RESTful design and database storage.

**Context:** I have a note resource. Users can have many notes. Each note can have many tags.

**Functional Goals:**
I need to create routes to do the following:
1) Fetch all user tags. Something like: `GET /users/:id/tags`
2) Delete tag(s) associated with a note.
3) Add tag to a specific note.

**Data/Performance Goals**
1) Fetching user tags should be fast. This is for the purpose of "autosuggest"/"autocomplete".
2) Prevent duplicates (as much as possible). I want tags to be reused as much as possible for the purpose of being able to query data by tag. For example, I'd like to mitigate scenarios where the user types a tag such as "superheroes" when the tag "superhero" already exists.

That being said, the way I see it, there are two approaches of storing tags on a note resource:

1) tags as nested property. For example:

```
type: 'notes',
attributes: {
  id: '123456789',
  body: '...',
  tags: ['batman', 'superhero'] 
}
```

2) tags as their own resource. For example:

```
type: 'notes',
data: {
  id: '123456789',
  body: '...',
  tags: [1,2,3] // <= Tag IDs instead of strings
}
```

Either one of the approaches above could work but I am looking for a solution that will allow scalability and data consistency (imagine a million notes and ten million tags). At this point, I am leaning toward option #1 since it is easier to cope with code wise but may not necessarily be the right option.

I am very interested in hearing some thoughts about the different approaches especially since I cannot find a similar questions on SO about this topic.

**Update**
Thank you for the answers. One of the most important things for me is identifying why using one over the other is advantageous. I'd like the answer to include somewhat of a pro/con list.

Comment: Are you talking about this while storing in DB or when output is returned from rest?

Comment: Does a tag have any other information besides a name and perhaps an ID?

Comment: Tags only contain a string value. This question touches both RESTful design and DB storage - I've updated my question to reflect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Considering your requirements, IMO you should store `tags` as resources and your API should return the `notes` with the tags as embedded properties.

---

## Database design

Keep `notes` and `tags` as separate collections (or tables). Since you have many notes and many tags and considering the fact that the core functionality is dependent on searching/autocomplete on these `tags`, this will improve performance when searching for `notes` for particular `tags`. A very basic design can look like:

**notes**

```
{
    'id': 101,    // noteid
    'title': 'Note title',
    'body': 'Some note',
    'tags': ['tag1', 'tag2', ...]
}
```

**tags**

```
{
    'id': 'tag1',    // tagid
    'name': 'batman',
    'description': 'the dark knight',
    'related': ['tagx', 'tagy', ...],
    'notes': [101, 103, ...]
}
```

You can use the `related` property to handle duplicates by replacing `tagx`, `tagy` by similar `tags`.

---

## API Design

**1. Fetching `notes` for `user`:**

```
GET /users/{userid}/notes
```

Embed the `tags` within the `notes` object when you handle this route at backend. The `notes` object your API send should look something like this:

```
{
    'id': 101,
    'title': 'Note title',
    'body': 'Some note',
    'tags': ['batman']    // replacing the tag1 by its name from tag collection
}
```

**2. Fetching `tags` for `user`:**

```
GET /users/{userid}/tags
```

If it's not required, you can skip on sending the `notes` property which contains the `id` for your `notes`.

**3. Deleting `tags` for `notes`:**

```
DELETE /users/{userid}/{noteid}/{tag}
```

**4. Adding `tags` for `notes`:**

```
PUT /users/{userid}/{noteid}/{tag}
```

Addressing the performance issues, fetching `tags` for `user` should be fast because you have a separate collection for the same. Also, handling duplicates will be simpler because you can simply add the similar `tags` (by `id` or `name`) into the `related` array. Hope this was helpful.

---

## Why not to keep tags as nested property

- The design is not as scalable as the previous case. If the `tags` are nested property and a `tag` has to be edited or some information has to be added, then it will require changes in all the `notes` since multiple `notes` can contain the same `tag`. Whereas, keeping the `tags` as resources, the same `notes` will be mapped with their `ids` and a single change would be required in the `tags` collection/table.
- Handling duplicate `tags` might not be as simple as when keeping them as separate resources.
- When searching for `tags` you will need to search for all the `tags` embedded inside every `note`. This adds overhead.

---

The only advantage of using `tags` as nested property IMO is it'll make it easier to add or delete `tags` for a particular `note`.

Comment: Note that depending on your underlying database, you may want an [associative table](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity).

Comment: One thing I am not seeing in your answer is a reason for choosing one approach over another. Why should I be treating tags as a separate resource?

Comment: I've added a few more points for using the `tags` as property. Hope this makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a little bit complicated. So I can just share my experience with `Tag` work (in our case, it was a main feature of VoIP App).

In any case all `Tags` will be as unique object, which contains a lot info. As you know it would be a more complicated for transferring, but you would need this information, for example below. And sure, Json it's fastest solution.

```
type: 'notes',
data: {
  id: '123456789',
  body: '...',
  tags: [UUID1,UUID2,UUID3] 
}
```

Just for example, how much of information you would needed. When you want to change color of tag, or size, based on Tag Rate, color based on number usage, linked (not same), duplicates, and so on.

```
type: 'tag',
data: {
  uuid: '234-se-324',
  body: 'superhero',
  linked: [UUID3, UUID4]
  rate: 4.6,
  usage: 4323
  duplicate: [superheros, suppahero]
}
```

As you can see, we use even duplicates. Just to save uniques of every `Tag`. Sure we also contain logic to filter the Words Root, but as you can see from example above, we also use duplicate value with special Roots, like "Superhero" and "Suppahero" which are same for us.

And you might think, this is a lot information for the "autosuggest" or "autocomplete", but we never faced performance issues (in case, if sever side support sanity). And all information is important for every usage, and `Note` in this case too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One thing I am not seeing in your answer is a reason for choosing one approach over another. Why should I be treating tags as a separate resource?

Answer (score 1):

Saving tags as nested property makes sense if you want to have all data in same row. Let me give you an example.

On invoice you add items,

Title, description, price, qty, tax, ...

tax in this case could be : VAT 20% so you calcualte invoice with 20%, but one day tax changes to 22% and all invoices that are saved on DB will be 2% more. In this case you add new column and you save it as raw number 20, and when you read that invoice from db you get all data from one row, instead of calculating it from different tables or variables.

Same thing is with tags. If you somehow want to merge duplicates, its easy to do it with IDs rather than strings.

Also there are some other factors that you might consider it.

> in a social network, a user might have tags that are called skills, interests, sports, and more. There is no real way to differentiate between tags *from (https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on)*

So if you are making tags that you will tag many things you have to use id